# Multiple account activity from current session

Tags: gmail

The account activity pop up shows three rows which are starred (*).

[image: screen shot from activity page]

A starred-row shows activity from current session.

How can there be 3 activity from same session? I logged in around 10:30, which is shown in the 3rd row, then the 2 rows above that are also starred, which I am clueless about.

Could anybody please explain what is happening? And, is this common? I have not logged in using any other device and I always use browser only.

Comment: Are you implying that you logged out / closed the browser session soon after "10:41am"? Or was the browser session left open during this time?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail does a lot of stuff<sup>1</sup> in the background. Depending on cookies, rotating IP addresses, etc., it's not uncommon to see multiple connections from the same "session".

I have a boat load of open sessions when I look at the same tool.

What you're seeing is normal, and not something to worry about. I would only be worried if it showed your account as being "open in another location". Good on you for looking, though. Most people don't.

<sup>1</sup> Retrieving email, refreshing ads, etc.